# Не дописывает в файл все значения

Tags: c#, windows, файлы, windows-7, windows-10

Данный код выполняет запись в файл (выполняется в Windows 10):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Documents\JS\1.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i<=100000;i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Однако в конце файла я обнаруживаю:

```
99882
99883
99884
99885
99886
99887
99888
99889
99890
9
```

Если после цикла использую

```
sw.Close();
```

то всё нормально. На работе на ПК с Windows 7 он дописывает до конца.

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamWriter` и прочие средства для записи в файл, как правило, используют буфер в памяти, чтобы писать в файл блоками.
Для очистки буфера (и записи данных из него в файл) используется метод `.Flush()`. Метод `.Close()` также приводит к очистке буфера, хоть это и не основное его назначение.
То что на каком-то устройстве у вас дописывалось до конца - это, что называется, "повезло".

Answer (score 4):

Вы не закрыли `StreamWriter`.

Используйте `using`:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Documents\JS\1.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i<=100000;i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}
```